# pass a string from managed C# to managed C++

Tags: c#, .net, c++, string

what is the preferred method to pass a string between C++ and C#?

i have a c++ class where one of the functions takes a `char const * const` as parameter.

how would i call this function in C#? just using a c#-`string` doesnt seem to work as the function in C# requires a `sbyte*`

C++ class:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    void Sample(char const * const Name);
}
```

Error   2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'sbyte*'

thanks!

Comment: Can you show your function prototypes and the code giving you an error?

Comment: yepp, i have edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using managed C++, you can use System.String class

Answer (score 1):

You need to try casting your parameter in C# as an sbyte.

```
Sample((sbyte)nameOfParameter);
```

That should then work fine.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way would be to write a wrapper in C++/CLI that uses `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` or something like that to convert the System::String^ to a char pointer and than call that wrapper from C#.